# how can i store a record having multiple rows into a hive table?

Tags: hive

I have a data file having data like the following:

```
10 CLARK,1,265, KING,3,2145, MILLER,2,255
20 ADAMS,2,234, FORD,2,141, JONES,2,425, SCOTT,3,346, SMITH,4,252
30 ALLEN,2,141, BLAKE,3,2145, JAMES,2,255, MARTIN,2,255, TURNER,2,255, WARD,2,255
```

I need to store them in a hive table. Since the values are veriying, kindly suggest how I can create a table to store such records.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can do:

1. If the maximum number of columns are fixed (say 20 at max), then you have a hive table with that many columns. Hive will automatically assign null to the columns which don't exist in any particular row.
2. Other thing you can do is to store each row as a string and while querying you can split on that string. However this wouldn't be great because every time while querying you will have to split first and then run your queries.